# How to update a row in table with angular-material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm build an app with `angular` and `C#`. for styling I'm using `angular-material`.

I have a report component which display a table with data.

I want to support update and delete actions. I have services for delete and update.

What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Show some code pls

Comment: there're severals examples, e.g. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57524126/is-there-any-way-to-edit-specific-column-of-table-using-mat-table-in-angular-mat/57535385#57535385 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64075553/how-to-implement-edit-update-and-discard-functions-in-angular-material-tablema/64077774#64077774, but if you don't show us what are you trying is difficult help you

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples about removing specific rows from the mat-table:

- Remove action for each row: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-remove-row-and-adapters?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
- Choose one or more rows to remove in once https://stackblitz.com/edit/delete-rows-mat-table?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.ts

You can use those examples to implement the edit action in the same way as the remove action.